# Space created at the bottom of a panel with foundation framework

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm playing with foundation framework and i'm trying to make a simple login form with it.
Here's my markup

```
<form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-4 columns">   
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <label>Login: <input type="text" placeholder="Login">
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <label>Senha <input type="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">                                                       
                            <input type="submit" value="OK" class="tiny button right">
                            <a href="#" class="left">Esqueci minha senha</a>
                        </div>      
                    </div>                      
                </div>              
            </div>
        </form>
```

But at the bottom of it, there's some space created. [image]
How can i remove this space?

Answer (score 0):

The space you are talking about is created by the buttons bottom margin. To remove it simply add a CSS class like such:

```
.panel .button { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Working example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/j06rcaxq/)